# Why both the set and unset commands don't work as expected in my macOS terminal

Tags: linux, shell, environment-variables, zsh, unset

> I'm very confused by this result.

I have two questions.

1. What's wrong with that?
2. What are `*`, `@`, and `argv`?

```bash
$ set GITHUB_ENV_var=1
$ echo $GITHUB_ENV_var

# ❌ after set, echo nothing
$ set | grep GITHUB_ENV_var
'*'=( 'GITHUB_ENV_var=1' )
@=( 'GITHUB_ENV_var=1' )
argv=( 'GITHUB_ENV_var=1' )

$ unset GITHUB_ENV_var
# ❌ unset no work at all
$ set | grep GITHUB_ENV_var
'*'=( 'GITHUB_ENV_var=1' )
@=( 'GITHUB_ENV_var=1' )
argv=( 'GITHUB_ENV_var=1' )
```

I'm using the `zsh` as the default shell.

[image]

### expect result

```bash
$ set GITHUB_ENV_var=1
$ echo $GITHUB_ENV_var
1
```

### update

I know that I can use `export GITHUB_ENV_var=1` to set a system-wide variable value, but I wonder why the `set` and `unset` commands did not work as expected.

[image]

Comment: This _isn't_ what `set GITHUB_ENV_var=1` is expected to do. Look for its documentation in `man zshbuiltins`, or by running `help set` in bash.

Comment: `set` is not meant to set a variable. Maybe you mean `let`? `let GITHUB_ENV_var=1` would make sense for variables which should hold integer values. But the variable would still **not** end up in the environment.

Comment: @user1934428, ...using `let` to introduce an arithmetic context is ancient pre-POSIX syntax (that the Austin Group deliberately chose not to incorporate into the standard) only supported by modern shells for backwards compatibility; better to let it die.

Comment: BTW, `export var=value` is **not** local; environment variables have even wider scope than normal shell globals, because unlike normal shell variables they're copied to child processes.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : I know, and it would be better than to write `((var=value))`, but I thought that maybe the OP confused `set` and `let` due to its similar spelling.

Comment: _to set a local variable value_ : To set a **local** variable, you would use `local name=value`. This would restrict the scope of `name` to the current function. I don't know whether zsh allows a variable to be _local_ and _export_ at the same time. This would be an environment variable which automatically gets undefined when the function ends. Why do you need this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I'm really sorry for asking this question without fully understanding the "set" command.

I understand three things after reading the book `Linux Command Line and Shell Scripting Bible, 3E`

1. The `set` command is not designed for setting environment variables;
2. The `export` command is used to set system-wide environment variables;
3. When I learned that the `unset` command can delete environment variables, I mistakenly thought that the `set` command and the `unset` command were the opposite functions;

```bash
$ man zshbuiltins


       set [ {+|-}options | {+|-}o [ option_name ] ] ... [ {+|-}A [ name ] ]
           [ arg ... ]
              Set the options for the shell and/or set the positional parameters, or
              declare and set an array.  If the -s option is given, it causes the
              specified arguments to be sorted before assigning them to the positional
              parameters (or to the array name if -A is used).  With +s sort arguments
              in descending order.  For the meaning of the other flags, see
              zshoptions(1).  Flags may be specified by name using the -o option. If no
              option name is supplied with -o, the current option states are printed:
              see the description of setopt below for more information on the format.
              With +o they are printed in a form that can be used as input to the shell.

              If the -A flag is specified, name is set to an array containing the given
              args; if no name is specified, all arrays are printed together with their
              values.

              If +A is used and name is an array, the given arguments will replace the
              initial elements of that array; if no name is specified, all arrays are
              printed without their values.

              The behaviour of arguments after -A name or +A name depends on whether the
              option KSH_ARRAYS is set.  If it is not set, all arguments following name
              are treated as values for the array, regardless of their form.  If the
              option is set, normal option processing continues at that point; only
              regular arguments are treated as values for the array.  This means that

                     set -A array -x -- foo

              sets array to `-x -- foo' if KSH_ARRAYS is not set, but sets the array to
              foo and turns on the option `-x' if it is set.

              If the -A flag is not present, but there are arguments beyond the options,
              the positional parameters are set.  If the option list (if any) is
              terminated by `--', and there are no further arguments, the positional
              parameters will be unset.

              If no arguments and no `--' are given, then the names and values of all
              parameters are printed on the standard output.  If the only argument is
              `+', the names of all parameters are printed.

              For historical reasons, `set -' is treated as `set +xv' and `set - args'
              as `set +xv -- args' when in any other emulation mode than zsh's native
              mode.
```

Answer (score 2):

In zsh, like in bash and sh, you don't use `set` to assign a variable. Just do:

```
$ GITHUB_ENV_var=1
```

If you want the variable to be available to other commands (not just shell builtins), use `export`:

```
$ export GITHUB_ENV_var=1
```

Comment: No, that doesn't explain my problem.

Comment: Why not? You are trying to assign to a variable using a shell builtin, `set`, that has a different purpose.

Comment: @Thomas: You're right, of course, but maybe you could update your answer to explain what `set` _does_ do - not least because it explains the other things that xgqfrms is finding strange?

Comment: @psmears I would love to, but `man zsh` doesn't explain it, and the online documentation is currently... [not online](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/) (getting `SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP`).

Comment: @Thomas: OK fair enough: the [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/set.html) page for `set` explains it, but it's pretty opaque. Basically `set one two three` sets the positional parameters `$1`, `$2` etc to (in this case) `one`, `two` and `three`. That's why you see `$@` and `$*` in the output - these expand to show all of `$1`, `$2` etc, and in this case `$1` is being set to `GITHUB_ENV_var=1`.

Comment: `man zshbuiltins` (or `man zshall` with a bit more scrolling) has the documentation of the `set` command.